nuxt 2.18 app created with 'npx create-nuxt-app ...' has TypeError('invalid options argument') when starting npm run dev
Today I ran npx create-nuxt-app <nuxt app name goes here> and after completing the create / install I ran npm run dev just to spin it up and check everything.
npm run dev executes about half-way through then has error:
.../node_modules/mkdirp/lib/opts-arg.js:13 throw new TypeError('invalid options argument')
I've done the usual web searching for a solution. There are a lot of discussions about this, all with different solutions that aren't very clear. I'm not sure on how to fix this. Any suggestions?

The solution at this link worked for me.
TLDR: Put the following as the last entry of your package.json file
"overrides": {
    "nuxt": {
      "@nuxt/webpack": {
        "mkdirp": "0.5.6"
      }
    }
}

